# Simple $avg in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Im trying to calculate the average of fields using a aggregation pipeline in MongoDb.

My test data in `test` colleciton is:

```
[{ _id: aaaaa, aa: 3, bb: 4},
 { _id: bbbbb, aa: 5, bb: 6},
 { _id: ccccc, aa: 7, bb: 8}]
```

Following the instructions on **MongoDB** site: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/

I devised my query as:

```
 db.getCollection('test').aggregate([ {$project:  { AVGaabb: { $avg: ['$aa','$bb'] } } }])
```

Yet if I run this query in Robomongo I get:

```
assert: command failed: {
    "errmsg" : "exception: invalid operator '$avg'",
    "code" : 15999,
    "ok" : 0
} : aggregate failed
```

Am I understanding the $avg query wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In version [3.2](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/) $avg is available in the $group and $project stages. In previous versions of MongoDB, $avg is available in the $group stage only.

So if you use a previous version, you have to create a $group stage instead of the $project stage.

I have tested in one of my mongos (3.2.7):

```
> db.stackoverflow.aggregate([{$project:{ "AVGaabb": { $avg: ["$aa","$bb"] }}}])
{ "_id" : ObjectId("578fa20574b924681b055c95"), "AVGaabb" : 3.5 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("578fa20b74b924681b055c96"), "AVGaabb" : 5.5 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("578fa21074b924681b055c97"), "AVGaabb" : 7.5 }
```

Comment: I'm hosting the DB on compose, and the version is 3.2.7.. However I'm calling aggregate from a Robomongo client connection. Could it be because of Robomongo?

Comment: try to run it with a mongoclient through command prompt or a terminal

Comment: Aaahh. thanks. you where right. I'm running this DB on modulus which is V3.0 and when I tested it on the compose DB which is V3.2, it worked. Thanks.